# Disable specific W3C Logging Field

Tags: iis, logging

Is there a command or PS command to disable a specific W3C Logging Field?

I know you can just go to IIS manager and uncheck the box but I have a few hundred servers to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a powershell command for this:

```
Set-WebConfigurationProperty
```

You can generate your command easily in the IIS GUI. Choose the server (top-level of IIS), then Configuration Editor. Go to section 'system.applicationHost/log'. Make your edits, then find the 'Generate Script' link.

Here is a quick example from something I use for our app servers.

```
Set-WebConfigurationProperty -pspath 'MACHINE/WEBROOT/APPHOST'  -filter "system.applicationHost/log/centralW3CLogFile" -name "logExtFileFlags" -value "Date,Time,ClientIP,UserName,SiteName,ComputerName,ServerIP,Method,UriStem,UriQuery,HttpStatus,Win32Status,TimeTaken,ServerPort,UserAgent,Referer,HttpSubStatus"
```

If that gives you trouble, you could also use the appcmd tool with something like this (update MySiteName to your IIS site name, and id='6' to the ID of your web site):

```
C:\windows\system32\inetsrv\Appcmd set config -section:sites /[name='"MySiteName"',id='6'].logFile.logExtFileFlags:Date,Time,ClientIP,UserName,ServerIP,Method,UriStem,HttpStatus,Win32Status,TimeTaken,ServerPort,UserAgent,Cookie,HttpSubStatus
```

Comment: wow it even gives you the script in different dialog like PS or Command line, even java. thank you so much!

Comment: update: so i tried to use both appcmd and ps commands but it is still not disabling the field i dont want inside W3C logging fields. after command is run and i go to check if box has been unchecked, it is still checked.

Comment: Did you run    iisreset after updating the config?

Comment: yes iisreset was done and cookie field was still checked after script and reset.

Comment: I'm not sure what is going on there... I've just updated my post to show another method using appcmd.exe. It is not as pretty... At least the way I have used it in the past, I had to apply changes to each website in IIS (rather than globally in IIS).